# Angular routing path matching using route parameters

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a route config that will match the path :id/compA, otherwise fallback to the route that has the :tab route parameter.  The :tab route always seems to match regardless of order.

How do I do this?

Thanks!

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: ':id/compA',
        component: SpecificComponent
    },
    {
        path: ':id/:tab',
        component: GeneralComponent
    }
];
```

Comment: Angular by default looks at parameterised routes first and then non parameterised ones. So `:id/:tab` takes precedence over the other one. I guess you might wanna redesign your routes and components. But anyway, 2 consecutive parameters in the routes don't look like a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I agree that I should take another approach here with my path matching.

Answer (score 2):

You could try giving [UrlMatcher](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher) a try.

You could setup some custom logic for route matching.